# Automated unit testing for database dependent application

Tags: database, unit-testing, tdd

I am working on C++ application which has huge dependency on database. If I need to implement automated unit testing what is the best option?

1. Insert dummy data in DB which your test function requires and the call test function.
2. Modular DB operation code and processing code but may not be feasible in legacy code.
3. Override DB Operation so that specific data can be return instead of actual DB hit; looks complex.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a Unit Test would not interact with a database, these would be Integration Tests, as you want your unit tests to be fast and independent (FIRST principle).
This may only be possible if you have clean separation between objects and DB interaction.
One good compromise that maybe worth considering is to use an in memory database for the unit tests, as this will allow the tests to run quickly and allow flexibility with resting data between tests.

On key thing to consider is how and when to reset the database to ensure tests are independent and can run in any order, unless you specifically write tests to run in a given sequence.

Then maybe write an Integration Test using the actual database for completeness.